# Как сохранить фото в PyQt5

Tags: python, pyqt5

При нажатии на кнопку `загрузить фото` должно вылезать диалоговое окно, в котором можно выбрать фото, а потом это же фото должно `сохранится в другой папке`. Помогите с реализацией.

```py
    def setupUi(self, SecondWindow):
        SecondWindow.setObjectName("SecondWindow")
        SecondWindow.resize(224, 197)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(SecondWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.formLayoutWidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.formLayoutWidget.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 221, 131))
        self.formLayoutWidget.setObjectName("formLayoutWidget")
        self.formLayout = QtWidgets.QFormLayout(self.formLayoutWidget)
        self.formLayout.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        self.formLayout.setObjectName("formLayout")
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.formLayoutWidget)
        self.label.setObjectName("label")
        self.formLayout.setWidget(0, QtWidgets.QFormLayout.LabelRole, self.label)
        self.lineEdit = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.formLayoutWidget)
        self.lineEdit.setObjectName("lineEdit")
        self.formLayout.setWidget(0, QtWidgets.QFormLayout.FieldRole, self.lineEdit)
        self.label_2 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.formLayoutWidget)
        self.label_2.setObjectName("label_2")
        self.formLayout.setWidget(1, QtWidgets.QFormLayout.LabelRole, self.label_2)
        self.lineEdit_2 = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.formLayoutWidget)
        self.lineEdit_2.setObjectName("lineEdit_2")
        self.formLayout.setWidget(1, QtWidgets.QFormLayout.FieldRole, self.lineEdit_2)
        self.label_3 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.formLayoutWidget)
        self.label_3.setObjectName("label_3")
        self.formLayout.setWidget(2, QtWidgets.QFormLayout.LabelRole, self.label_3)
        self.lineEdit_3 = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.formLayoutWidget)
        self.lineEdit_3.setObjectName("lineEdit_3")
        self.formLayout.setWidget(2, QtWidgets.QFormLayout.FieldRole, self.lineEdit_3)
        self.label_4 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.formLayoutWidget)
        self.label_4.setObjectName("label_4")
        self.formLayout.setWidget(3, QtWidgets.QFormLayout.LabelRole, self.label_4)
        self.comboBox = QtWidgets.QComboBox(self.formLayoutWidget)
        self.comboBox.setObjectName("comboBox")
        self.formLayout.setWidget(3, QtWidgets.QFormLayout.FieldRole, self.comboBox)
        self.label_5 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.formLayoutWidget)
        self.label_5.setObjectName("label_5")
        self.formLayout.setWidget(4, QtWidgets.QFormLayout.LabelRole, self.label_5)
        self.lineEdit_4 = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.formLayoutWidget)
        self.lineEdit_4.setObjectName("lineEdit_4")
        self.formLayout.setWidget(4, QtWidgets.QFormLayout.FieldRole, self.lineEdit_4)
        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 130, 111, 23))
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")
        self.pushButton_2 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(110, 130, 111, 23))
        self.pushButton_2.setObjectName("pushButton_2")
        SecondWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.menubar = QtWidgets.QMenuBar(SecondWindow)
        self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 224, 21))
        self.menubar.setObjectName("menubar")
        SecondWindow.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(SecondWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        SecondWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)

        self.retranslateUi(SecondWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(SecondWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, SecondWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        SecondWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("SecondWindow", "MainWindow"))
        self.label.setText(_translate("SecondWindow", "ФИО"))
        self.label_2.setText(_translate("SecondWindow", "Школа"))
        self.label_3.setText(_translate("SecondWindow", "Класс"))
        self.label_4.setText(_translate("SecondWindow", "Пол"))
        self.label_5.setText(_translate("SecondWindow", "дата Рождения"))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("SecondWindow", "Загрузить фото"))
        self.pushButton_2.setText(_translate("SecondWindow", "Добавить"))
```

Comment: Опубликуйте пожалуйста то, что у вас есть.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Как вариант:

```
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
import shutil                    # cм. https://pythonworld.ru/moduli/modul-shutil.html

class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, SecondWindow):
        SecondWindow.setObjectName("SecondWindow")
        SecondWindow.resize(224, 390)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(SecondWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.formLayoutWidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.formLayoutWidget.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 221, 131))
        self.formLayoutWidget.setObjectName("formLayoutWidget")
        self.formLayout = QtWidgets.QFormLayout(self.formLayoutWidget)
        self.formLayout.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        self.formLayout.setObjectName("formLayout")
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.formLayoutWidget)
        self.label.setObjectName("label")
        self.formLayout.setWidget(0, QtWidgets.QFormLayout.LabelRole, self.label)
        self.lineEdit = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.formLayoutWidget)
        self.lineEdit.setObjectName("lineEdit")
        self.formLayout.setWidget(0, QtWidgets.QFormLayout.FieldRole, self.lineEdit)
        self.label_2 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.formLayoutWidget)
        self.label_2.setObjectName("label_2")
        self.formLayout.setWidget(1, QtWidgets.QFormLayout.LabelRole, self.label_2)
        self.lineEdit_2 = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.formLayoutWidget)
        self.lineEdit_2.setObjectName("lineEdit_2")
        self.formLayout.setWidget(1, QtWidgets.QFormLayout.FieldRole, self.lineEdit_2)
        self.label_3 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.formLayoutWidget)
        self.label_3.setObjectName("label_3")
        self.formLayout.setWidget(2, QtWidgets.QFormLayout.LabelRole, self.label_3)
        self.lineEdit_3 = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.formLayoutWidget)
        self.lineEdit_3.setObjectName("lineEdit_3")
        self.formLayout.setWidget(2, QtWidgets.QFormLayout.FieldRole, self.lineEdit_3)
        self.label_4 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.formLayoutWidget)
        self.label_4.setObjectName("label_4")
        self.formLayout.setWidget(3, QtWidgets.QFormLayout.LabelRole, self.label_4)
        self.comboBox = QtWidgets.QComboBox(self.formLayoutWidget)
        self.comboBox.setObjectName("comboBox")
        self.formLayout.setWidget(3, QtWidgets.QFormLayout.FieldRole, self.comboBox)
        self.label_5 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.formLayoutWidget)
        self.label_5.setObjectName("label_5")
        self.formLayout.setWidget(4, QtWidgets.QFormLayout.LabelRole, self.label_5)
        self.lineEdit_4 = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.formLayoutWidget)
        self.lineEdit_4.setObjectName("lineEdit_4")
        self.formLayout.setWidget(4, QtWidgets.QFormLayout.FieldRole, self.lineEdit_4)

        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 130, 111, 23))
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")

        self.pushButton_2 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(110, 130, 111, 23))
        self.pushButton_2.setObjectName("pushButton_2")

        SecondWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)

        self.menubar = QtWidgets.QMenuBar(SecondWindow)
        self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 224, 21))
        self.menubar.setObjectName("menubar")
        SecondWindow.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(SecondWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        SecondWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)

        self.retranslateUi(SecondWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(SecondWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, SecondWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        SecondWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("SecondWindow", "MainWindow"))
        self.label.setText(_translate("SecondWindow", "ФИО"))
        self.label_2.setText(_translate("SecondWindow", "Школа"))
        self.label_3.setText(_translate("SecondWindow", "Класс"))
        self.label_4.setText(_translate("SecondWindow", "Пол"))
        self.label_5.setText(_translate("SecondWindow", "дата Рождения"))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("SecondWindow", "Загрузить фото"))
        self.pushButton_2.setText(_translate("SecondWindow", "Добавить"))


class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.setupUi(self)

        self.label = QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 170, 200, 200))
        self.imagePath = ''

        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.openImage) 
        self.pushButton_2.clicked.connect(self.saveImage)        


    def openImage(self): 
        # выбрать фото
        self.imagePath, _ = QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(self, "Select Image", "", 
                                   "Image Files (*.png *.jpg *.jpeg *.bmp)")

        pixmap = QPixmap(self.imagePath)
        self.label.setPixmap(pixmap.scaled(200, 200))

    def saveImage(self):
        # это же фото должно сохранится в другой папке
        if self.imagePath:
            print(self.imagePath)
            options = QFileDialog.Options()
            options |= QFileDialog.DontUseNativeDialog
            fileName, _ = QFileDialog.getSaveFileName(self,"SaveFileName","",
                          "Image Files (*.png *.jpg *.jpeg *.bmp)", 
                          options=options)
            if fileName:
                print("файл для Сохранения: ", fileName)

                shutil.copy(self.imagePath, fileName)          # !!!



if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    mainWindow = MainWindow()
    mainWindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]